# React Native, FlatList does not output my list correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this quite easy items where I normally loop over with `map`:

```
{items.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <Item
      desc={item.desc}
      done={item.done}
      index={index}
      key={index}
      onSetDone={setDone}
    />
  );
})}
```

The above code works fine, but as I learned, it is better do use `FlatList` in my components do render something in a loop. So I tried the following:

```
<FlatList
  data={items}
  renderItem={(item, index) => (
    <Item
      desc={item.desc}
      done={item.done}
      index={index}
      onSetDone={setDone}
    />
  )}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
/>
```

The correct amount of items are rendered, but unfortunately, none of the props gets passed to the Child component. Getting `undefined undefined true`.

What am I doing wrong here? Why is my data not correctly passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not giving `renderItem` a function with the right parameter. Here is its signature from the [doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#required-renderitem):

```js
renderItem({ item, index, separators })
```

Change your code to this:

```js
<FlatList
  data={items}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
    <Item desc={item.desc} done={item.done} index={index} onSetDone={setDone} />
  )}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
/>
```