# FlatList not rendering on list of text

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

New to react native. I have a simple component that takes in a list of ingredients and returns the items in a flatList of text. For some reason I can't get the data to render. Am I doing something wrong?
My ingredients looks like this:

```
const ingredients = [chicken, butter, oil]

const DisplayRec = ({ ingredients }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Your Recipes</Text>
      <FlatList
        //keyExtractor={(recName) => recName}
        data={ingredients}
        renderItem={({ recName }) => (
          <Text>{recName}</Text>
          
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native, FlatList does not output my list correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73262058/react-native-flatlist-does-not-output-my-list-correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using it in incorrect manner
please try

```
 <FlatList
    //keyExtractor={(recName) => recName}
    data={ingredients}
    renderItem={({item, index}) => (
      <Text>{item}</Text>
      
    )}
  />
```

also please go throught the documentation of FlatList
https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#required-renderitem

Answer (score 1):

> First you have to go through with the official documentation of
> React-native .
> [flatlist documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#required-renderitem)

> you can just simply pass ingredients data to flatlist and render its
> function

[For live editing expo link](https://snack.expo.dev/@muhammadabdullahrishi/api-flatlist)

```
const ingredients = [
  {
    id: 'bd7',
    title: 'chicken',
  },
  {
    id: '3ac',
    title: 'butter',
  },
  {
    id: '5869',
    title: 'oil',
  },
];

export default function App() {

const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
   <Text>{item.title}</Text>
  );

  return (
    <View >
       <FlatList
        data={ingredients}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
   
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use return in render item

```
<FlatList
            //keyExtractor={(recName) => recName}
            data={ingredients}
            renderItem={({ recName }) => {
            return (
            <Text>{recName}</Text>
              
            )}}
          />
```

Hope it's working fine for you